# Rails ActionView Missing Template during Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an email using ActionMailer.
The invoice email gets sent.

But, I'm getting this error on the screen after the emails is sent:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /invoices/sendinvoice
Missing template invoices/sendinvoice, application/sendinvoice
```

This is in my invoices_controller.rb

```
  def sendinvoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
    InvoiceMailer.invoice_email(@invoice).deliver
  end
```

This is in mailers/invoice_mailer.rb

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "ndeavor@ameipro.com"
  def invoice_email(invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    mail(:to => @invoice.workorder.contact.email, :subject => "New Invoice from " + @invoice.tenant.name )
  end
end
```

This is in views/invoice_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Invoice</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a button in the invoices/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Send Invoice', invoices_sendinvoice_path(:invoice_id => @invoice), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

This is in routes:

```
  get "invoices/sendinvoice"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to specify one view when the email is sent. Your action does not have a view and rails is asking for that. The view should be in app/views/invoices/sendinvoice.html.erb